# Why can't I accept a client?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking

I started a simple server that connects to a client, it worked a month ago but now it doesn't.

**main**

```
def main():
    (client_socket, client_address) = start_server(('0.0.0.0', 8200))

    print("online")
    menu = """
        enter the mode wanted out of:
        write,
        random,
        cal,
        file,
        close to terminate connection"""
    menu = menu.encode()
    main_menu(client_socket, menu)
    client_socket.close()
    server_socket.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**start_server function**

```
def start_server(addr):
    global server_socket
    server_socket = socket.socket()
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind(addr)
    server_socket.listen(1)
    (client_socket, client_address) = server_socket.accept()
    return client_socket, client_address
```

The server doesnt run the `server_socket.accept()` and i get this error for the client :

> OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context

**client socket**

```
    my_socket = socket.socket()  # creates the socket
    my_socket.connect(('0.0.0.0', 8200))  # connects to the server
    choose_mode(my_socket)  # main menu
```

why does it not accept the client?

Comment: Bind the server to to 0.0.0.0, connect the client to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: It fixed the problem, but could you explain to me why?

Comment: Because 0.0.0.0 isn't a target address to connect to, and binding to 127.0.0.1 is generally too restrictive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bound 0.0.0.0 and 8200 but connected to 127.0.0.1.
**server**
`(client_socket, client_address) = start_server(('0.0.0.0', 8200))`
**client**
`my_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8200))  # connects to the server`

As I was explained:
because 0.0.0.0 isn't a target address to connect to, and binding to 127.0.0.1 is generally too restrictive

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're trying to start a server in your localhost. Depending on the platform/ OS this code is running on, this address can be invalid . Perhaps this is what has changed, your underlying platform.

To avoid the issue ,   use

```
start_server((socket.gethostname(), 8200))
```

or

```
start_server(('127.0.0.1', 8200))
```

You can read more about using 0.0.0.0 below.

https://www.howtogeek.com/225487/what-is-the-difference-between-127.0.0.1-and-0.0.0.0/

Comment: Just link the original source: https://superuser.com/a/949522/999318

Comment: I changed it and now I get this error 
>ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it